# Search zipped files and list content

Tags: search, zip

I have a folder with many archive files.

How can I search all the files and list their content (possible extract to excel or to any other document) of the zipped files without extracting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of your problem is well explained just [here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/9356/7-zip-how-to-list-contents-of-a-folder-and-subfolder-of-zip-files-without-extracting-win-xpvista7-and-command-line/), that's using 7zip and a batch (`.bat`) script.

> 7-Zip: How to list contents of a folder and subfolder of zip files without extracting (Win XP,Vista,7 and Command Line)

1. Download and install 7-Zip.
2. Navigate to the 7-Zip install directory (C:\Program Files\7-Zip) and copy these three files and paste them into a folder  on our desktop called “7zip” : **7z.exe**, **7z.dll**, **7z.sfx**
   These files will be used with our batch (.bat) file we create to do our directory listing and content listing of the zip file.
3. Open Notepad (Start Menu > type `notepad` or press the Windows key + R and type `notepad`, then press enter.)
4. Insert this code (copy and paste from below) into Notepad.

   `FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.zip') do (7z.exe l -r "%%A" >> listing.txt)`
5. Then click on File > Save. Browse to our Desktop and the 7zip folder. Click the “Save as type:” drop-down and choose “All Files“. Give it a name of ziplist.bat and hit the Save button.
6. Copy the four files from the 7zip folder on our desktop: 7z.dll, 7z.exe, 7z.sfx, ziplist.bat to the folder that contains the zip files and other sub-folder of zip files.
7. Finally, run the ziplist.bat by double-clicking on it.  This batch file will do the following using a FOR statement:

It will do a directory listing of the current folder and all subfolders for any file with a .zip extension.  If it finds any, it will then send the path to 7-zip’s command line exe and then output the contents listing to a text file called listing.txt.  This file will be saved in the same folder that the ziplist.bat is located in.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.